# Setting up oauth for JIRA 6.4

Tags: jira, oauth

I want to setup oauth for third party application to log jira issues in jira 6.4.

I am familiar with twitter oauth process.

But looking at jira oauth, its taking too much time.
I have been able to create external application link so far.

I have the following question in filling up the form "Incoming Authentication" section?

1. Is there any way to generate consumer key or public key in the form?
2. Should i fill consumer key, just any thing..? If so then how should i generate the public key?

Then filling up the third party application oauth form, they ask following thing which are unknown to me

1. consumer key : Should it be the same as i filled up in above form?
2. Consumer Secret : Where should i get or generate this secret?

I have been through [this](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Linking+to+Another+Application) but i could not help myself this.

Comment: Did you ever manage to figure this one out?

Comment: nope, i am working around with basic oauth so far. And m still seeking for working example for jira oauth.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I think I might be onto something.. Once I have figured it out I will post an answer. :)